# css creating a big gap in layout issue

Tags: css

I have an issue with the following layout in css, as you can see from the image below the two floating elements to the far right have got a big space between them.

[image: messy 3 column css layout]

and I'm trying to get them to line up like

[image: clean 3 column css layout]

I'd rather not use negative margins to pull 'sidebar2' into the right spot and the 'mag link' has to separate from the second sidebar.

thanks

```
            <!doctype html>
            <html lang="en">
            <head>
            <meta charset="utf-8" />
            <title></title>
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
            <!--[if IE]>
            <script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
            <![endif]-->
            </head>
            <body>
            <div class="wraper clearfix">

            <div class="container clearfix">  

            <header>header</header>

            <div class="carousel">carousel</div>

            <div class="posts">posts
            <div class="post">Post</div>
            <div class="post">Post</div>
            <div class="post">Post</div>
            <div class="post">Post</div>
            <div class="post">Post</div>
            <div class="post">Post</div>
            </div>

            <div class="sidebar1">sidebar1</div>

            <div class="mag-link">mag link</div>

            <div class="sidebar2">sidebar2</div> 

            </div><!-- container -->
            <footer class="clearfix">footer</footer>      
            </div><!-- wraper -->

            </body>
            </html>
```

css

```
            .wraper {
            background-color: rgba(254,139,206,0.27);
            width: 100%;
            position: absolute;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            }

            .container {
            background-color: rgba(253,184,65,0.27);
            width: 1040px;
            margin: 0 auto;
            padding: 0;
            }

            header {
            background-color: rgba(198,247,73,0.27);
            margin: 0 0 16px 0;
            padding: 0 16px 16px;
            height: 292px;
            }

            .carousel {
            background-color: rgba(96,250,193,0.27);
            margin: 0 8px 16px 0;
            height: 240px;
            width: 720px;
            display: inline-block;
            overflow: hidden;
            float: left;
            }

            .posts {/* page content */
            background-color: rgba(94,93,250,0.27);
            width: 512px;
            float: left;
            display: inline-block;
            padding: 0;
            margin: 0 8px 16px 0;
            }

            .post {
            width: 290px;
            height:200px;
            }

            .sidebar1 {
            background-color: rgba(184,88,250,0.27);
            display: inline-block;
            padding: 0;
            margin: 0 8px 16px 8px;
            float: left;
            position: relative;
            width: 208px;
            height:800px;
            }

            .mag-link {
            background-color: #fd9e90;
            width: 240px;
            height: 200px;
            margin: 0 0 16px 8px;
            float: left;
            position: relative;
            bottom: 389px;
            display: inline-block;
            }

            .sidebar2 {
            background-color: rgba(251,244,57,0.27);
            float: left;
            width: 240px;
            height:1100px;
            margin: 0 0 16px 8px;
            display: inline-block;
            }


            footer {
            width: 100%;
            background: #fd9e10;
            height: 312px;
            float: left;
            }

            .clearfix {
            zoom: 1; }
            .clearfix:before, .clearfix:after {
            content: "";
            display: table; }
            .clearfix:after {
            clear: both;}
```

Comment: Please set up an example on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)

Comment: after your header, you should split your page into two columns and put the corresponding elements in either the left or right column

Comment: Here it is jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/34FMg/

Comment: Thats a good idea Pete, I'll give that a go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this: 
http://jsfiddle.net/A2XVQ/1/

i just remove some properties

**HTML**

```
            <div class="container clearfix">  

            <header>header</header>

            <div class="carousel">carousel</div>

            <div class="posts">posts
            <div class="post">Post</div>
            <div class="post">Post</div>
            <div class="post">Post</div>
            <div class="post">Post</div>
            <div class="post">Post</div>
            <div class="post">Post</div>
            </div>

            <div class="sidebar1">sidebar1</div>

            <div class="mag-link">mag link</div>

            <div class="sidebar2">sidebar2</div> 

            </div><!-- container -->
            <footer class="clearfix">footer</footer>      
            </div><!-- wraper -->
```

**CSS**

```
.wraper {
            background-color: rgba(254,139,206,0.27);
            width: 100%;
            position: absolute;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            }

            .container {
            background-color: rgba(253,184,65,0.27);
            width: 1040px;
            margin: 0 auto;
            padding: 0;
            }

            header {
            background-color: rgba(198,247,73,0.27);
            margin: 0 0 16px 0;
            padding: 0 16px 16px;
            height: 292px;
            }

            .carousel {
            background-color: rgba(96,250,193,0.27);
            margin: 0 8px 16px 0;
            height: 240px;
            width: 720px;
            display: inline-block;
            overflow: hidden;
            float: left;
            }

            .posts {/* page content */
            background-color: rgba(94,93,250,0.27);
            width: 512px;
            float: left;
            display: inline-block;
            padding: 0;
            margin: 0 8px 16px 0;
            }

            .post {
            width: 290px;
            height:200px;
            }

            .sidebar1 {
            background-color: rgba(184,88,250,0.27);
            display: inline-block;
            padding: 0;
            margin: 0 8px 16px 8px;
            float: left;
            position: relative;
            width: 208px;
            height:800px;
            }

            .mag-link {
            background-color: #fd9e90;
            width: 240px;
            height: 200px;
            margin: 0 0 16px 8px;
            position: relative;
            display: inline-block;
            }

            .sidebar2 {
            background-color: rgba(251,244,57,0.27);
            float: left;
            width: 240px;
            height:1100px;
            margin: 0 0 16px 8px;
            }


            footer {
            width: 100%;
            background: #fd9e10;
            height: 312px;
            float: left;
            }

            .clearfix {
            zoom: 1; }
            .clearfix:before, .clearfix:after {
            content: "";
            display: table; }
            .clearfix:after {
            clear: both;}

}
```

good luck

Answer (score 0):

You need to place the content part (including the carousel, posts and the first sidebar) into one div and the two elements to the right (mag link and sidebar 2) into a second div and float them left.

HTML would look like that:

```
 <div class="wraper clearfix">

        <div class="container clearfix">  

        <header>header</header>

        <div class="contentwrap">

     <div class="carousel">carousel</div>

        <div class="posts">posts
        <div class="post">Post</div>
        <div class="post">Post</div>
        <div class="post">Post</div>
        <div class="post">Post</div>
        <div class="post">Post</div>
        <div class="post">Post</div>
        </div>

        <div class="sidebar1">sidebar1</div>

     </div>

     <div class="sidebarwrapper">
        <div class="mag-link">mag link</div>

        <div class="sidebar2">sidebar2</div> 
     </div>

        </div><!-- container -->
        <footer class="clearfix">footer</footer>      
        </div><!-- wraper -->
```

Have a look at my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jW6HW/

Comment: Thanks guys I would give you both a green tick if I could.